# UI Slider with Time and parseInt

Tags: jquery, slider, parseint

This following JavaScript fragment is not working:

```
$('#slider_1').slider({
   value: parseInt($('#um_field_16_1').val(), 10),
   min: 0,
   max: 1440,
   step: 1,
   slide: function(event, ui) {
      var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.value[0] / 60);
      var minutes1 = ui.value[0] - (hours1 * 60);
      if(hours1.length < 10) {
         hours1= '0' + hours;
      }
      if(minutes1.length < 10) {
          minutes1 = '0' + minutes;
      }
      if(minutes1 == 0) {
         minutes1 = '00';
      }
      $('#um_field_16_1').val(hours1+':'+minutes1);
   }
});
```

Has somebody an Idea how I can get the value with parseInt? I get NaN:NaN Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it appears that the field called `um_field_16_1` can be set with a value that looks to be of the format `nn:nn`.  The `:` symbol will prevent you from being able to parse this value as an integer.  See the [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) documentation for allowable strings.

If you have a string value of the format `hh:mm` and want to convert to the number of minutes, one possibility would be:

```
var s = "05:20";
var parts = s.split(":");
var minutes = 60*parseInt(parts[0]) + parseInt(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the Idea was "60*parseInt" :-) This works for me.